# How do I get started with my first simulation in Orbiter?

Tags: orbiter

I've just got Orbiter installed and working, and my 'Scenarios' are all just empty folders. The only thing that allows me to 'Launch orbiter' is my 'Current state', which is just a pre-recorded demo. How do I get started? Do I need to install add-ons first?

Answer (score 1):

Ummm. I needed to double click the folders not single-click!